# How can I know that a user really login using OpenID or just pasting the URL from the previous login?

Tags: php, lightopenid

I have two pages: **login.php** and **return.php**.  Both use **LightOpenID**.

The page **login.php** creates a link to an OpenID provider and tells the provider to return the result to **return.php**

The following are the normal flow of using those two pages.

1. Go to **login.php** and click the link.
2. Login using a Google account.
3. The system redirects to **return.php** and shows that User ... has logged in.

However, later on, I can make **return.php** says the same thing even I don't do Step 2 by pasting the URL of **return.php** with its query string (copy from Step 3).

How can I know that a user really login using OpenID or just paste the URL from the previous login?

Here are the code:

**login.php**

```
<?php
require_once 'openid.php';

$openid = new LightOpenID("mydomain.com");
$openid->identity = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id';
$openid->returnUrl = 'http://mydomain.com/return.php'
?>

<a href="<?= $openid->authUrl() ?>">Login</a>
```

**return.php**

```
<?php
require_once 'openid.php';

$openid = new LightOpenID("mydomain.com");
if($openid->mode) {
  echo 'User ' . ($openid->validate() ? $openid->identity .  ' has ' : 'has not ') . 'logged in.';
} elseif($openid->mode == 'cancel') {
  echo 'User has canceled authentication!';
} else {
  echo 'Please go to login.php';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$openid->validate()` will return `true` only once per authentication. If an user attempts to login again using the exact same url (i.e. same nonce, etc.), `$openid->validate()` will return false. At least that's the case if the provider works according to the spec. If it doesn't, there's almost nothing you can do.

Answer (score 0):

The document of LightOpenId not help. But this question could help: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995011/log-in-the-user-with-lightopenid)