# how to auto login to another html page from flex

Tags: apache-flex, redirect, autologin

I have a flex application. From this application I want to navigate to another url which is a html page. To do that I can use navigateToURL() method. In the new url I have to login. I need to automate the login into the page. For example if I am in a flex app, then clicking on a button I should auto login to my gmail page in another tab. I have all the necessary credentials in the flex app itself Has anybody done that?

Answer (score 0):

If you use OpenId you could have one login for many sites. You'd have to *start* with GMail, FBook or some provider like that and you could move to your Flex site. I don't know about going the other way around though.

More info:

- [openid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995011/log-in-the-user-with-lightopenid)
- [facebook login](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/)

Comment: I have a button on my flex app. On click on this can I go to my gmail or any page in another tab and automatically login into that, just like this facebook login?

Comment: You would start with a unified login that would give you FB, Gmail, Yahoo or related. Then use this for all of the apps( including yours ). Once you had the 'global login' credentials you could move from your app to GMail, FB, etc.

Comment: You didn't get my question. I want to navigate to any page from my flex application which is a web application. In the newly opened webpage I don't want to login again. I need to take care of that from my flex application itself.

Comment: Right - what I'm saying is that GMail, FB, etc aren't going to let another app authenticate for them. It's the other way-round. If you use openid at the outset you can then move from your app to the other service(s). AFAIK you can't provide login params for these big services in the URL.